# Running bash command through ssh that only exists on remote

Tags: bash, ssh, command-line-interface

I am writing a bash script that involves ssh-ing into a remote host and running commands there. That in itself is not a problem. The issue is that I want to run a command which doesn't exist locally, only on the remote. The script fails with `bash: line 1: type: remote_only_command: not found`, even though it's successfully connecting to the remote host and can run basic commands without issue.

I can run the command on the remote host if I ssh in and run it manually. I've tried writing a separate bash script on the remote host and running that through the script (`sh remote_script.sh`), but that gets the same command not found error.

```
ssh $REMOTE var=$var 'bash -s' << 'EOF'
ls # works no problem, lists files on the remote server
remote_only_command # bash: line 1: type: remote_only_command: not found
EOF
```

Is it possible to run a command that is only accessible from the remote host and not locally where the script is being run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is the way it should work, as the command is only executed on the remote host. But i suspect your problem is the environment, which is NOT permitted over ssh. Try to use the complete path to the command, eg:

```
 /path/to/remote_command
```